# SQL query to group by chronological series

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'm working on a business case where people visit locations at different times.

I need to group each series at the same location and return it as one row.

To illustrate, I've created and populated the table *visit* (see below).

`select loc, hour from visit order by hour` gives me

```
Loc Hour
1   10
1   11
1   12
2   13
2   14
1   15
1   16
```

I would like an SQL that returns the following:

```
Loc first last
1 10 12
2 13 14
1 15 16
```

Suggestions, anyone?

---

Table / data in example

```
create table visit ( loc number(2), hour number(2) );

insert into visit (loc, hour) values (1,10);
insert into visit (loc, hour) values (1,11);
insert into visit (loc, hour) values (1,12);
insert into visit (loc, hour) values (2,13);
insert into visit (loc, hour) values (2,14);
insert into visit (loc, hour) values (1,15);
insert into visit (loc, hour) values (1,16);
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typical gaps-and-islands problem, where you want to group together "adjacent" visits at the same location.

Here is one way to solve it using the difference between `row_number`s:

```
select 
    loc,
    min(hour) first_hour,
    max(hour) last_hour
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by hour) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by loc order by hour) rn2
    from visit t
) t
group by loc, rn1 - rn2
order by first_hour
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5a06d9055926e51fcb96c88606bc4469)**:

```
loc | first_hour | last_hour
--: | ---------: | --------:
  1 |         10 |        12
  2 |         13 |        14
  1 |         15 |        16
```